# USB stopped working after kernel update

Tags: boot, usb, kernel, xhci-hcd

My USB ports stopped working under Ubuntu 12.04 after kernel update to 3.3.6-030306. I get an error message during boot process as "xhci_hcd can't set up". Details:

```
> dmesg | grep xhci
[    0.906495] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: found PCI INT A -> IRQ 10
[    0.906509] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: sharing IRQ 10 with 0000:00:1c.3
[    0.906565] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.906600] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    0.906648] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: can't setup
[    0.906652] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
[    0.906704] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: init 0000:04:00.0 fail, -19
```

When I boot Windows 7, the USB ports are working fine. I have a 4-year old Dell XPS 15z, BIOS is from then:

```
> sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date
01/13/2012
> sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
A09
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: You might know this, but you have the capability to boot to previous kernels

Comment: Thanks, pfeiffep. I tried this (choosing kernel vmlinuz-3.2.0-99-generic manually from the grub), but all I got was just a black screen, I waited for about 2min,  and then I didn't know what to do, so I booted again into vmlinuz-3.3.6-030306-generic.  Any advise?

Comment: Still no solution. I cannot boot any previous kernel. I discovered that the xhci module seems to have crashed entirely after boot, "lsmod | grep xhci" returns nothing.  If there are any other informations required, please tell me, thanks

Comment: OK, I can boot kernel 3.2.0-101-generic, but the output of dmesg is still the same, still no xhci, and still no USB ports